# CPU core stuck at 100% utilization

Tags: dell, cpu-load, top, intel-cpu

I noticed that my laptop's fans were running continuously at high RPM for a few hours. I installed HTOP to check CPU utilization, and found that one of the 8 cores is stuck at 100%. Even after multiple reboot, this would happen. I reinstalled the OS, but same problem reoccurs. Specs - Dell Latitude E5470; Intel i7 6820HQ; 32 GB  RAM; 250GB PCIE SSD; Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Screenshot below shows the output of HTOP. Using this and TOP command, i tried to find the process that was causing this high CPU utilization, but HTOP doesn't show any application at the top. Also, the process consuming the highest CPU is using 5%, but one core is constantly pegged at 100%.

I have installed all the Ubuntu OS and Dell firmware updates.

Any ideas on how i can debug this?

[image]

UPDATE - I have isolated the process that is causing this. Its the Chrome browser. I ran the laptop for a week, without firing up Chrome, and no fan issues. The moment i fire up Chrome and start watching videos, Fans kick in. And they stay on long after i have closed Chrome.

Comment: Note - One of my concerns was that my machine might have been infected by a miner or malware of some kind. Which is I why i did a fresh OS install. Didn't help.

Comment: If that's the case I'd be curious if it happens when booted into a Live CD or similar

Comment: I sure can boot it into a Ubuntu Live CD and run it for a few days. But this thing is my daily driver and i would like to try other non-interrupt-y things before i attempt that :)

Comment: So running Ubuntu live (same version as you've got installed) works normally, all 4 cores are at regular/low levels? Tried `sudo htop` and it's the same?

Comment: Just ran sudo htop for an hour. Same results. Havent tried liveCD yet.

Answer (score 1):

I would try looking at Session and Startup. Check the Autostart tab where you can find the programs that are starting at time of OS boot. Turning these applications off and then back on again may give you an idea which one is pegging the core of concern. If that particular application is discovered, arrive at an understanding of whether it is needed. If needed, perhaps some web search or contacting the developer may provide some answers. If not needed, perhaps the best solution is to remove from the Autostart list.

Comment: I checked, and i dont have any user-installed programs starting at boot.